# How do you change between guitar types in Rocksmith?

Tags: rocksmith

I have two different guitars I like to switch between every so often. These guitars have two different headstocks though.

[image: 6 inline vs 3x3 headstocks]

I set the game up originally for my 6-in-line guitar, but now I want to switch to a 3x3. How do I get back to this option, without restarting the game?

Comment: Does this actually affect gameplay? The tuner might display the 'wrong headstock', but you know which tuning knob corresponds to the 'correct headstock'. So does it really matter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to the Amp and then Guitar Select. You can equip any of the guitars you have unlocked.

The headstock and the fretboard style of the guitar you choose will determine the headstock and fretboard used throughout the game.